# Reading data from firebase no setter field errors Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello im trying to retrive data from all notes from the current logged in user.

however i keep getting this error and i dnt know how to fix this. im using Viewholder recyclerView. i also have 2 xml files 1 for the view and one for the cardview layout. however i know the problem is in my code section where i'm missing to read out the data. i saw a tutorial and we do the same thing he also creates posts with user ID and reads them out like this

Error listed below:

> ```
> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -LxFfo5HuRPQsBUSiFuc found on class com.example.examapplikation.Models.NotesList
>
> No setter/field for -LxFfqThHtNWsk9bD5Zb found on class com.example.examapplikation.Models.NotesList
>
> No setter/field for -LxI2a7Osg8WYK1E5VJ4 found on class com.example.examapplikation.Models.NotesList
> ```

these are the IDS of my posts:

my main activity

```
enter code here

 private RecyclerView recyclerView; //https://camposha.info/android-firebase-realtime-database-with-recyclerview/
    private FloatingActionButton addNotePageButton;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference todoDb;

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<NotesList> options;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NotesList, NoteViewHolder> adapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        addNotePageButton = findViewById(R.id.fab_button_addPage);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); // get inSTACE
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        todoDb = database.getReference("NoteList");
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager(this) );
        showTask();



        addNotePageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //  Float button click
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, NoteInputActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }


    private void showTask(){
       options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<NotesList>()
               .setQuery(todoDb,NotesList.class)
               .build();

       adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NotesList, NoteViewHolder>(options) {
           @Override
           protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull NotesList model) {
               holder.text_title.setText(model.getText());
               holder.text_content.setText(model.getText());

           }

           @NonNull
           @Override
           public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

               View itemView  = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                       .inflate(R.layout.notes_each_row,viewGroup,false);


               return new NoteViewHolder(itemView);
           }
       };

       recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);




}
```

here is my model class:

```
enter code here

public class NotesList {

    private String title;
    private String text;

    public NotesList(){

    }

    public NotesList(String title, String text){

        this.title=title;
        this.text= text;

    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

here is my code of my ViewHolder:

```
enter code here

public class NoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView text_title, text_content;

    public NoteViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView){

        super (itemView);

        text_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
        text_content = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_content);


    }

 }
```

database strucutre picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJn3h.png)

Comment: Add your database structure

Comment: i added the link in the post

Comment: You have to go one more level in your query to get `NotesList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go one more level in your query to get `NotesList`. Change your query like below:

```
todoDb = database.getReference("NoteList").child("6Dp...Py1");
```

if `6Dp...Py1` is your current user's `UID` then use

```
todoDb = database.getReference("NoteList").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

Comment: it worked til today now i got the same error again...